# Need help with the Formula Field in Salesforce. I must have not entered the formula properly. Need help

Tags: formula

For the purpose of having a prospect list as a report, I would like to show up in the report only leads/contacts in a campaign member list owned by the logged in User AND the leads owned by a queue. So I created a formula field as a checkbox and added it to the report as a filter. Here the formula:

```
AND( Lead.Owner:Queue.Id="3D00G50000002l3Sw",
    IF($User.Id=Contact.OwnerId, TRUE,
    IF($User.Id=Lead.Owner:User.Id, TRUE,
    IF($User.Id=Contact.Account.OwnerId, TRUE,
    FALSE
))))
```

Comment: Is the formula saving? If so, how does its output differ from what you're expecting?

Comment: formula is saving but output is null.  I am making it as a dynamic report

Comment: formula is saving but output is null.  I am making it as a dynamic report. Condition for 
OR I am the lead owner, show me the lead in the report
OR I am the contact owner, show me the contact in the report,
OR I am the account owner, but not the contact owner, still show  me the contact in the report

AND
No matter what is true above show me all leads owned by X queue

So as a result I should have at least in my report the leads owned by the queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bartosz's advice about using the the Queue Developer Name is good, but there are a couple other issues here. (Incidentally, the problem with your Queue Id is that it has "3D" at the front, probably from copying it out of an encoded URL. "00G50000002l3Sw" is probably the Queue Id you're looking for, but, **use the developer name**.)

First, and most important, is that you are using `AND()`, which means that **all** of the conditions listed have to be `TRUE` for the checkbox to be `TRUE`. It's not possible for a Lead to be owned both by a queue and the current user, so your formula as written will always be `FALSE`. You want any one of the conditions to make the checkbox formula `TRUE`, so you need to use `OR()`.

Another point, not really an error, is that checks for equality are inherently `TRUE` or `FALSE`; you don't need to wrap them in an `IF()` to determine that.

So, that gets us to:

```
OR(Lead.Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = "QueueDevName", 
$User.Id=Contact.OwnerId, 
$User.Id=Lead.Owner:User.Id, 
$User.Id=Contact.Account.OwnerId)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Personally, I avoid use of those horridly confusing AND and OR functions and stick with something like "Lead.Owner:Queue.DeveloperName = "QueueDevName" || $User.Id=Contact.OwnerId || $User.Id=Lead.Owner:User.Id || $User.Id=Contact.Account.OwnerId", but then I'm a programmer rather than business analyst :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all `3D00G50000002l3Sw` is definetely not a Queue's Id, so probably that's where you are having issues. Also: as a general rule, try not to use hardcoded Ids anywhere in Salesforce because they may change (e.g. during deployment to another environment). Instead use DeveloperName or similar field. Try using this formula:

```
AND( Lead.Owner:Queue.DeveloperName="Developer_Name_Of_Your_Queue",
    IF($User.Id=Contact.OwnerId, TRUE,
    IF($User.Id=Lead.Owner:User.Id, TRUE,
    IF($User.Id=Contact.Account.OwnerId, TRUE,
    FALSE
))))
```

And change `Developer_Name_Of_Your_Queue` to whatever your Queue's Developer Name is.

Comment: thanks for the help